# Не происходит вызов из приложения

Tags: android

Подскажите почему такой простой код и не работает?

```
public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + "5551222"));
```

В манифесте прописал

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
```

При нажатии на кнопку не происходит ничего.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

вы забыли

```
startActivity(intent);
```